# Webpack is not get config path, path must be string, received null

Tags: reactjs

My reactjs web app use webpack, on `Mac` it has got correct config and running well but on window it always reports as "Path must be string, received null" (i think cause webpack is not get config params on window), do you know whats problem there please?

- I did tried `console.log` paths used to build js code from webpack config and its return correct path(on **window**)
- I did tried run `node_modules/bin/webpack` and it's running correctly.

But seem be its still not get correct configs.

- Package.json:

  ```
  "build": "node tools/build",
  ```
- tools/build.js:

  ```
  // Process CLI arguments
  const argv = process.argv.slice(2);
  const writeStatsJson = argv.indexOf('--stats') !== -1;

  if (writeStatsJson) {
      return bfj
             .write(`${paths.appBuild}/bundle-stats.json`, stats.toJson())
             .then(() => resolve(resolveArgs))
             .catch(error => reject(new Error(error)));
  }
  ```
- paths.js

> ```
> module.exports = {
>   appPath: resolvePath('.'),
>   appAssets: resolvePath('assets'),
>   appBuild: resolvePath('build'),
>   appHtml: resolvePath('assets/index.html'),
>   appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolvePath, 'src/index'),
>   appModernizr: resolvePath('src/vendor/modernizr-custom.js'),
>   appModernizrrc: resolvePath('src/vendor/modernizrrc.json'),
>   appPolyfills: resolvePath('src/polyfills'),
>   appSrc: resolvePath('src'),
>   config: resolvePath('config'),
>   dotenv: resolvePath('.env'),
>   nodeModules: resolvePath('node_modules'),
>   packageJson: resolvePath('package.json'),
>   publicPath: resolvePath('/'),
>   test: resolvePath('test'),
>   };
> ```

-webpack.config.js

```
output: {
      chunkFilename: isProd ? 'scripts/js/[name].[git-hash].chunk.js' : '[name].chunk.js',
      filename: isProd ? '[name].[git-hash].js' : '[name].js',
      path: paths.appBuild,
      pathinfo: isDev,
      publicPath,
      // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isProd
        ? info => path.relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        assets: paths.appAssets,
        modernizr$: paths.appModernizrrc,
        test: paths.test,
        'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
      },
      modules: [paths.appSrc, paths.nodeModules],
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    }
```

I did `console.log paths.appBuild` its return correct folder